# Создать новые строки используя часть значений из других строк

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть dataFrame с набором данных такого вида(в столбце Spisok_STS может быть n СТС, разделитель - запятая):

```
user_id;Spisok_STS;grz
1;50XE516421;Н123ЕТ150
2;9942987177;Т321НТ178
3;5144574666;NaN
4;9928966790,5133657517;В111ТУ31
```

Мне требуется найти все строки с 2 и более СТС и оставить по одному СТС в каждой строке:

```
user_id;Spisok_STS;grz
1;50XE516421;Н127ЕТ150
2;9942987177;Т648НТ178
3;5144574666;NaN
4;9928966790;В955ТУ43
4;5133657517;В955ТУ43
```

Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

UPDATE:
Попробовал решить через цикл, но, кажется, это далеко не самое лучшее решение.

```
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if "," in df['Spisok_STS'][i]:
        pos = df['Spisok_STS'][i].find(',')
        part1 = df['Spisok_STS'][i][:pos]
        part2 = df['Spisok_STS'][i][pos + 1:]
        user_id_i = df['user_id'][i]
        df.loc[len(df.index)] = [user_id_i, part2, 0]
        df.loc[i, 'Spisok_STS'] = part1
```

Comment: Что уже пробовали делать?

Comment: Мое решение добавил в пост. Если вы сможете подсказать как его улучшить, было бы очень здорово)

Comment: Здорово, что добавили пример, но можно его превратить в [минимально воспроизводимый пример](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Режем строки в столбце `Spisok_STS` по запятым, получаем списки. Потом "эксплодим" (преобразуем каждый элемент списка в строку, повторяя значения индекса) этот столбец.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'user_id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Spisok_STS': ['50XE516421', '9942987177', '5144574666', '9928966790,5133657517'],
     'grz': ['Н123ЕТ150', 'Т321НТ178', np.nan, 'В111ТУ31']})
df = df.assign(Spisok_STS=lambda x:x.Spisok_STS.str.split(",")).explode('Spisok_STS')
print(df)
```

```
   user_id  Spisok_STS        grz
0        1  50XE516421  Н123ЕТ150
1        2  9942987177  Т321НТ178
2        3  5144574666        NaN
3        4  9928966790   В111ТУ31
3        4  5133657517   В111ТУ31
```